# AngularJS + easy pie chart - Animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Animation is not working, can't figure out how to fix it,
can you help?

i tired to make it work on jsfiddle but it's not working for some reason

html:

```
    <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', ['easypiechart']);
            app.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.percent = 65;
                    $scope.anotherPercent = -45;
                    $scope.anotherOptions = {
                            animate:{
                                    duration:100,
                                    enabled:true
                            },
                            barColor:'#2C3E50',
                            scaleColor:false,
                            lineWidth:20,
                            lineCap:'circle'
                    };
            }]);
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LVTM4/

but you can run download the example and run it, and see for yourself,

JQuery is working with animation, Angular is not
https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle is a mess.

You have your code set to 'onLoad' which means its being wrapped by jsfiddle to fire only after page load. Then you have script in the html itself, that script will fire out of time with the rest of the document. Also you have `<body>` tags in your html. Those should not be there in a fiddle. Lastly, you didn't even bootstrap the html, so angular would never run in the first place. Also you didn't even check to see if the directive fires at all.

This is a mess. Clean it up.

[Here's a slight leg up.](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/VZvLp/)

If you expect to get free help, at least don't waste everyones time with this kind of garbage.

---

Just a tip. Don't copy paste the plugin you want to test into jsfiddle. Include it as an external resource. That way your fiddle is just your implementation, which is all you should be testing anyway.

---

Here it is working in jsfiddle. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/qczb6/)

Comment: well it's not working now either, the "free help" is for helping others as well, as you see i really need help, so if you are not here for help, that's fine with me but please don't disturb

Comment: @LiadLivnat I am here to help. I have a track record of that here on SO. Clean up your fiddle, repost and I will help.

Comment: well i did what you said, and update the fiddle it is still not working, i gave the download like to the github so you can download it from there if you want to help.

Comment: I'm sure it works as intended. Please post your updated fiddle.

Comment: i can't make it work in js fiddle, can you download it from here?  https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

Comment: @LiadLivnat sure. What are you asking then? That I download the plugin ? Then what?

Comment: then tell me why if you can make the animation working on the example attached in the link like i aseked in the question, it is the same code as in jsfiddle but it is working when will download it you will see  run the angular.html file.

Comment: @LiadLivnat there is no value in that. You already have a sample were it is working. What is the point of me making you another sample of it working? If you try again with jsfiddle I will help show you were you went wrong, but you need to try harder than this: http://jsfiddle.net/LVTM4/. If you have a sample of it working, then the plugin obviously does work. Its that you don't understand it, and me making another sample will do nothing to help you there.

Comment: @LiadLivnat do you see the line of code there `animate:{
            duration:0,
            enabled:false
        },` ? Its looking like you don't read code. The whole point is that you would LEARN how to implement, not hunt for snippets. I'm sorry. This is a waste of my time.